# PROBLEMA CON BOOSTRAP DENTRO DEL BODY

Tags: spring-boot, script, body, java-17

Ante todo, buenos días, tardes o noches, mi problema es algo basico, ya lo he solucionado pero de todas formas quisiera saber porque otros si pueden y otros no (en mi caso), lo que pasa es que estoy usando boostrap, estoy trabajando con un template para todas mis paginas, el template contiene un navbar con un dropdwon y un buscar, todo me corre bien, pero cuando le doy clic al dropdown no me sale el submenu con el item que tengo puesto ahi, se queda sin hacer nada, he colocado los scripts del boostrap al final del body no me funciona, pero lo coloque fuera del body osea en el html y si me funciona, no se que este pasando, les paso mi codigo para que me ayuden:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Spring eCommerce</title>


  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link th:href="@{vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet">
     <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div th:insert="~{administrador/template_admin.html::header}"></div>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Jumbotron Header -->
      <header class="jumbotron my-4">
        <h1 class="display-3">Bienvenido a Spring Ecommerce 2023</h1>
        <p class="lead">Tu tienda de productos en Línea</p>
      </header>

      <!-- Page Features -->
      <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x325" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Nombre del producto.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <a href="productohome.html" class="btn btn-success">Ver producto</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x325" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Nombre del producto.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Ver producto</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x325" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Nombre del producto.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Ver producto</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
          <div class="card h-100">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x325" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Nombre del producto.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Ver producto</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <div th:insert="~{administrador/template_admin.html::footer}">

    <script th:src="@{vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js}" ></script>
    <script th:src="@{vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js}" ></script>  
</body>
</html>
```